# How to show values as legend?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, bar-chart

I have a bar chart and I want to show the YAxis values as legends. The default behavior seems to be `Series` as legends...

[image: bar-chart]

How can I show the legend with YAxis values?

Comment: You need to use custom legend items: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456659.aspx

Comment: I am curious if you ever got this to work. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a new `LegendItem`.

```
LegendItem newItem = new LegendItem();
newItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.SeriesSymbol, "", ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
newItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, chartData[index].ToString(), ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
```

And do this for each series.